# Password policies at organization level versus profile level

Tags: profile, passwords, organization, policies

Hello,

There is something I would like to understand.
There are password policies at the organization level and at the profile level.
In the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_profiles_password_policies.htm&type=5), I can read the profile level overrides the organization level.
By default, it is the organization password policies if there is no profile password policies.

But because the password policies are required in the profile, how is it possible the organization password policies is the default?
I understand it is all the time the profile level which decides because per example, it is impossible the field "User passwords expire in" is empty.
If I have "30 days" in the profile and "60 days" in the organization, the final value for the profile will "30 days".

[image]

Do you have a documentation which explains it please?

Thanks

Comment: You've answered your own question: effectively it's always overridden. What is your concern?

Answer (score 0):

In a new org, there is a default Org-wide password policy which is applied to all Profiles.  If the password policy is changed at the org level, then that update is also made for Profiles which have *not* had the policy changed individually. In other words, once you change the password policy for an individual Profile, it detaches from auto-updates made at the org level; which is typical Object Oriented behavior. Hope this helps.